# Rename personal github account and create an organization by the old personal name

Tags: github, account

I am a freelancer and use my company name as the name of a personal Github account. Let's say that's: github.com/cool-company

I want to turn that into a company account by the same name, but when I do that any commits credited to cool-company will [no longer be linked to that account](https://help.github.com/articles/converting-a-user-into-an-organization/#convert-your-personal-account-into-an-organization-automatically). Also, I should create a new personal account before transforming cool-company into an organization.

This method creates the disadvantage that I lose perceived credits for my contributions I guess. For me as a freelancer that's not beneficial.

The solution I was thinking of is to first [rename](https://help.github.com/articles/what-happens-when-i-change-my-username/) my personal account from cool-company into one by my real name. That would keep all the history to my personal account.

After I'm done, would I be able to create a company account by the name of cool-company?

If that would work, I can add my personal account to the company account cool-company. Now, by my own name, I'd still have the history linked to my personal count and be a member of the company account cool-company.

Answer (score 0):

Since https://help.github.com/articles/what-happens-when-i-change-my-username/ says that "After changing your username, your old username becomes available for anyone else to claim", I assumed my approach should work. So I figured it was worth a try and see where I end up.

After renaming my personal account cool-company to my own name, which took a minute for Github to process, I created an organization by the name of cool-company. It works!

Be aware though that all your repositories are linked to your personal account now. If you intend to do what I did, but have all your repositories linked to the company account, you might want to reconsider your approach.